# Setting rowheight of Treeview makes other widget invisible in grid. Why this happens

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to make height of rows in a tree view taller by using ttk.Style.configure method. But, this makes other buttons invisible why does this happen? And how can I fix this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('My Awesome App')
        self.geometry('300x300')
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self, text='b1')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        self.b2 = tk.Button(self, text='b2')
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=120)  # this line makes app.b1, app.b2 invisible

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.b2.grid(row=2, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The height set for the tree is much higher than the height set for the root window, and even more than the height of some screens. If I add after `app=App()`: `app.update_idletasks(); print(app.tree.winfo_reqwidth(),app.tree.winfo_reqheight())`. The result will be: 203 and 1227. This is about 10 rows. You may also need to consider screen width and height.

Comment: @8349697 Why grid method does not resize app.tree? And How to make ttk.TreeView get automatically resized to fit master frame like other widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience place option gives move flexibility than grid. Here is an example which fixes the problem.

1. Divide your workspace into frames and put widgets into frames.
2. Pack widgets inside frame

   ```
   import tkinter as tk
   from tkinter import ttk


   class App(tk.Tk):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.title('My Awesome App')
           self.geometry('300x300')
           frame1 = tk.Frame(self, height = 50)
           frame2 = tk.Frame(self, height = 200)
           frame3 = tk.Frame(self, height = 50)
           frame1.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.1, relx = 0, rely = 0)
           frame2.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.8, relx = 0, rely = 0.1)
           frame3.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.1, relx = 0, rely = 0.9)
           self.b1 = tk.Button(frame1, text='b1')
           self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame2)
           self.b2 = tk.Button(frame3, text='b2')
           style = ttk.Style(self)
           style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=120)  # this line makes app.b1, app.b2 invisible

           self.b1.pack()
           self.tree.pack()
           self.b2.pack()


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app = App()
       app.mainloop()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tk.Treeview does not work well with geometry manager when it get size over master frame. So I end up make a method which recalculates column width and tree height based on the size of master and resize Treeview. Also, It needs to pack scrollbar first to prevent scrollbar from being hidden.

example:

```
class Treeview(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, container, columns, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Treeview, self).__init__(container, columns=columns, *args, **kwargs)
        self.columns = columns
        for column in self.columns:
            self.heading(column, text=column, anchor=tk.W)
            self.column(column, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    def update_man(self):  # call this method when treeview get update
        super(Treeview, self).update()
        mw, mh = self.master.winfo_width(), self.master.winfo_height()
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        row_height = style.lookup(self['style'], 'rowheight')
        ac = 1 if 'tree' in list([str(x) for x in self['show']]) else 0
        col_width = int(mw / (len(self.columns) + ac)) + 1
        for cn in range(len(self.columns)+1):
            self.column(f'#{cn}', width=col_width)
        if type(row_height) == 'int':
            row_view_height = int(mh / row_height)
            if row_view_height < self['height']:
                self['height'] = row_view_height
```